# Mendeley Desktop won't open on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mendeley

I've tried to run Mendeley on ubuntu 14.04. I installed it using the instructions on their website or by typing in the terminal sudo apt-get install mendeleydesktop and neither is working. Output of running mendeleydesktop on the terminal: "error while loading shared libraries: libsmime3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you are missing a library. If you search for `libsmime3.so` you will hit [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsmime3.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&arch=any) telling you that file is part of the `libnss3` library. So try:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

and then retry the mendeleydesktop installation.

Comment: But Ubuntu is not Debian. Use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ instead.

Comment: I've updated the link to point to the ubuntu package search tool. thanks